# PHP - Where to put it

Tags: javascript, php, html

Probably a very simple PHP question.  I'm just learning how to build my first website, that uses a database (and going to use PHP).   What is the common practice of where to put your PHP code? When I learned in Codecademy, the PHP was put right into my html (and I replace index.html with index.php).

When I go to websites like google, youtube or this one etc, you don't see any PHP in the html source code.  I'm assuming that the code is behind the scenes, like JavaScript.  Where do they put it?

Comment: *"When I go to websites like google, youtube or this one etc, you don't see any PHP in the html source code."* - And so you shouldn't. PHP parses the information and then renders it to a format (HTML) a browser will let you read.

Comment: On an added note, you can instruct Apache to treat `.html` `.htm` etc. as PHP.

Comment: I found this article that may be of some interest for you for starting a sevrer using Apache[one of my favorite servers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78152/what-is-the-best-place-to-put-php-files-above-server-root-directory)

Comment: @androidmaster The brackets go before the parentheses.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for pointing that out, hey hasnt this been asked before, I feel like it has...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP (and other server-side scripting languages, like Python and Ruby) only exists on the server, it doesn't get sent to the client. When you access a web page that's implemented using a server script, the server runs the script, and the script produces HTML as its output. This gets sent to the browser.

PHP can be somewhat confusing in this regard because it's an *embedded* language. You insert `<?php ... ?>` inside a block of HTML (or any other language). That looks kind of like HTML because of the `< ... >` bracketing, but it's not. The PHP processor starts out just copying the contents of the file to its output, but when it encounters `<?php`, it then starts processing it as executable PHP code until it encounters `?>` or the end of the file. But only the output of that code block is sent, not the block itself.

Comment: Such as when you use the Apache Server, you may have index.php or .html and the server only returns to the client the page. You don't see the PHP code just the final html code

Comment: *"it then starts processing it as executable PHP code until it encounters `?>`"* - Assuming there isn't any HTML below that. If there isn't, then the closing `?>` isn't necessary, although good practice.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server-side language, the web browser never sees the code. JavaScript and HTML are client-side, so the code is replicated and ran on the browser instead.

If you have this on a webpage:

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

The user will not see the code, they will only see "`hello`" (*minus the quotes*).

Comment: Gotchaaaaaa.  My fear was that if I programmed everything in PHP, and it was visible to end users, I could have an issue...

Comment: How did this answer get 4 upvotes in less than 5 minutes? I'll never understand the logic of some users on this site!

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob you mean downvotes? Or upvotes, because I only see downvotes

Comment: OK..I get it...very funny. Not understanding the logic of users...nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

Either in your html as

```
<?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

OR

create a file called `whatever.php` and put your php in there. Reference in your html by putting `<?php include 'whatever.php' ?>`

Make sure any file that has php code in it is saved with the `.php` extension

Answer (score 1):

Best practice now dictates that you keep any mixing of PHP and HTML to a minimum. The MVC ([model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) approach is one way of separating concerns in this way. There are various PHP frameworks which implement this approach and are good ways to familiarise yourself with it (e.g. [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/), [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter)).

Finally , in general, follow [these best practices with PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

EDIT: I didn't notice the last part of your question, but the others are correct: PHP is a server-side language (unlike Javascript) and therefore its code [can't be viewed client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563438/can-a-client-view-server-side-php-source-code).

Comment: But can JavaCript be viewed client side? Ie, is my javascript fair game to anyone?

Comment: Yes, though you could take measures to make it less readable by minifying it. AFAIK there's no cast-iron way to stop it being fair game though.

Comment: Got ya - thanks a lot.  Despite the downvotes, it was worth it. very handy all of this!  One last question... whats the best way to go about debugging PHP?  I used to use Visual Studio for C#, so I'm used to it throwing useful errors etc...

Comment: Good question -- I can't help with that, though notoriously PHP can be a pain to debug. Take a look at the Right Way site I linked to in my answer, might offer some clues.

Comment: No worries, and thanks a lot! I'm also debating between PHP and Rails.  Don't know much about it but from the sound of it its supposed to be easier... I tried asking on here, but that was also met with a wave of downvotes haha.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is download a software that will make your computer your own liitle server .

I suggest to download Webmatrix from microsoft but if you are using notepad that you should download software like xampp or wamp.

In webmatrix you just write the code and click run.

In xampp or wamp you need to get in to the directory of the softwareand search for a folder named www or htdocs. after you find them just copy your files to them turn on apache and go to `localhost` on your browser

you put the code itself in

```
<?php
 //code here
?>
```

just put it somewhere on the page.
for example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><?php echo "Hello, World!" ?></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you go to a website you will never see any php code in the Html source that your browser interprets.  Php is a server-side language so it is all completely processed and only its **output** is sent to the user.

Consider the following index.php file:

```
<?php
    echo 'Today\'s date is: ' . date("d.m.y");
?>
```

The Html would show the date, not the php code that retrieved the date, since all the processing was done by the server before it sent the result to you.